# Dental - Can 'Clip On Veneers' made of polymer ( or plastics ), be an alternative to a 'bridge' or 'implant' for a missing first-molar, for eating?

Tags: oral-health

Dental - Can Aesthetic 'Clip On Veneers' made of polymer ( or plastics ) that you can eat with, be an alternative to a 'bridge' or 'implant' for a missing first-molar ( for example ), **for the purpose of eating ?**

[image]

- I'm referring to Aesthetic 'Clip On Veneers' made of polymer ( or plastics ) that you can eat with.
- I'm referring to the Aesthetic 'Clip On Veneers' that completely cover all the upper, or lower teeth.
- Two different, un-connected providers of these Aesthetic 'Clip On Veneers', have told me you can eat wearing them, but obviously to avoid things like tough steaks or toffee etc.
- An additional question, that may not qualify for this forum - If they can be an alternative to a 'bridge' or 'implant' for a missing first-molar ( for example ), should government-dental-services provide these as an alternative to the public for the purpose of eating ( ? ).
- Here is a description -

  - https://wikitia.com/wiki/Clip-On_Veneers
  - https://www.fabsmileveneers.co.uk/eating-with-snap-on-veneers/
- Many people would like to find alternatives to a 'bridge' or 'implant', for a 'bridge', they turn the supporting molars or teeth ( normal healthy molars ) on each side of the gap into thin fence posts, and once a 'bridge' is completed some significant high risks remain, and an 'implant' is obviously also very very difficult.
- **NOTE - I just remembered 'Teeth-Shifting' / 'Dental-Drifting' when a molar or tooth is extracted and the gap is left empty, the adjoining molars or teeth drift into the gap, so, I don't know if that totally invalidates all of this question**.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please take a [tour] and visit the [help] for more information on the Medical Sciences Stack. Do you know the definition of "aesthetic"? How might this be different to a proper bridge or implant?

Comment: I have now included a photo and two links, these veneers just clip / slip onto the upper or lower teeth, so there's no actual dental procedure,    if you don't get them directly from a clinic, you can do it via postal-mail, they send you a mold to take an impression of the upper or lower teeth, you return the mold, and then they mail you the teeth / veneer

Comment: My questions still stand regarding definitions - I suggest you look up the word, I'll also suggest you look up the definition of veneer! These words both apply to your question.

Comment: Aesthetic veneers are **aesthetic**. Did you actually read the second link you provided? They're not replacement teeth and you can't chew food with them unless there's an actual tooth backing them, and even then there are limits on what you can eat.

Comment: These type of 'Clip On Veneers' made of polymer ( or plastics ), as in the photo above and the link, 'SEEM' to be completely unknown in actual dentistry, so I added the word "Aesthetic" to highlight that they are not part of actual dentistry, and the word "Veneers" is used by the companies selling some slightly different versions of these  "Veneers" ( some are completely made by the customer using a home molding kit. some are done at a professional via postal-mail )

Comment: The example company, I put a link for, mentions types of foods they recommend to eat, and types of food to avoid, other companies seem to mention other types of foods, but obviously they all say to avoid overly hard chewy foods or overly hard brittle foods.

Comment: I don't think you understood my point. Veneers *go over existing teeth*. They can't serve as substitutes for missing teeth.

Comment: The companies selling these types of veneers state that they can cover a continuous gap of a couple of teeth ( unless they mean a couple of gaps of single missing teeth, I can't remember ) , however, as I have now clarified my question - "NOTE - I just remembered 'Teeth-Shifting' / 'Dental-Drifting' when a molar or tooth is extracted and the gap is left empty, the adjoining molars or teeth drift into the gap, so, I don't know if that totally invalidates all of this question."

Comment: I'm sure they can probably cover a gap for aesthetic purposes, but you ask about eating with them. No way are you chewing with veneers alone.